# Is there a way to do something before OnAuthorize?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I add and/or remove the user from roles with `RoleSetter`, sign the user out, sign the user in, but the login page is still displayed, which tells me the authorization already happened.

My controllers `ActionMethod` is causing a login prompt and is decorated like this:

```
[RoleSetter(Order = 0)]
[Authorize(Roles = "project_user", Order = 1)]
public ActionResult Details(int? projectId)
{
    ...
}
```

`RoleSetter` is an AuthorizeAttribute that does some logic to add or/and remove the user from roles in asp.net-identity and looks like this:

```
public class RoleSetterAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public new void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        // Logic to add and/or remove roles
        ...
        // SignOut then SignIn to reset claims
        IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager = filterContext.HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication;
        authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        var identity = userManager.CreateIdentity(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = false }, identity);
    }
}
```

**Is there a way for my `RoleSetter` to execute before authorization executes?** I thought setting the `Order` would do it, but I still hit the login page. If I login, the roles were changed and the user is authorized to see the page; but they should never have seen the login page.

Comment: And your concrete question is?

Comment: @MikeSW I updated my question, added the concrete question and put it in bold.

Comment: This doesn't work because SignIn sets a cookie.  The problem is that the cookie has already been loaded by the time you are in this code.  If you log out or log in you *MUST* reload the page, there isn't another way around it.  This is really the wrong place to be doing this for a variety of reasons.  You also should never force a user to be signed out and signed in again silently like that.

Comment: You need to explain exactly what it is you're trying to accomplish with this RoleSetter attribute.  I mean besides, setting roles.  What is the purpose?  Why would you just want to force rules on a user when they navigate to a particular page?  More than likely, the root problem you are trying to solve can and likely should be accomplished a different way.  This is known as an XY Problem http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/134199

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I hear what you are saying. But, the purpose of the `RoleSetter` is just to set the user's roles based on the `projectId`. The project determines what roles they have. A user may be a `project_user` on one project but only a `project_reviewer` in another. So do you know of a different way to solve the problem? I thought about adding a `projectId` to the `AspNetUserRoles` table but the complexity of working with the way the AspNetIdentity system works with the authorization system was too much.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch So what I think I'll try as you mentioned above is two things. One, instead of signing in and signing out silently, I'll try adding and removing the roles to the current claims, which is all signing out and signing in is essentially doing. And two, if roles are changed, redirect back to the page.

Comment: @SeanStenlund - Typically roles are READ, not set when accessing a page.  In fact, I'm struggling to understand your use case as it really makes so little sense why you would want to set roles simply by accessing a page.  This is completely backwards.  A users roles are typically set by an administrator, not dynamically by simply accessing a page...

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch The roles are set by administrators--per project. And a user can belong to many projects. But the role (and thus the pages they can see) are dynamic depending on the project.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch So far example, if there was only one project in the entire web app, then the user's roles would never change unless they were promoted or explicitly given more roles.

Comment: @SeanStenlund - That makes no sense.  Roles are roles.  You just give the users Project1-AdminRole and Project2-AdminRole, there is no reason for any of this.  You assign Project1's admin sections to the Project1-AdminRole, etc.. it should all be static.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch There could be hundreds or more projects. And there are (currently) 6 roles. I wouldn't want to have to add roles "ProjectX-AdminRole", "ProjectX-ProjectUser", et cetera every time a project is added to the database. To me, that makes no sense.

Comment: @SeanStenlund - Your solution goes against the fundamental design of the way roles operate.. so regardless, you can keep fighting the system or work with it.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I don't believe it does. It has worked great thus far and I'm only trying to streamline it by making it an `AuthorizeAttribute` instead of a helper method. Do you know a better way or have seen a solution that works better? I'm open to suggestions. :)

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch I believe it is correct fundamentally because, only a `project_user` may add a widget to a project. So, `http://localhost/55555/Widget/Create?projectId=5` may only be accessed by a `project_user`. But I may not be a `project_user` on that project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a HttpModule and hookup on the PreRequestHandlerExecute event. Of course this means you won't be using anything Mvc related, but probably you don't need it anyway.

Comment: I think I do need the MVC related stuff. I want the `[Authorize(Roles = "project_user")]` to work. The user may not be in the `project_user` role after the `RoleSetter` executes. They might be in `project_reviewer` role.

Comment: Actually you don't need it for your RoleSetter. [Authorize] will trigger anyway, but your code only need HttpContext which is available in the http module

Comment: I'm confused; my problem is `[Authorize]` is triggering sending the user to the login page even though I have changed the roles for the user. If I login as the user, then it lets them in because it now recognizes they are in the role. I want the `[Authorize]` to check after I've changed the roles.

Comment: I see, try moving the code in a override of AuthorizeCore method then call the base method after your code. And probably you don't need the second Authorize. If that fails, then I'd use the http module approach

Comment: Okay, I'm trying your suggestion. However, it requires a `return true` or `return false`. Is there a way to return the result of `base.AuthorizeCore(filterContext)`. I'm only setting the roles in `RoleSetter` not determining if they are authorized.

Comment: just return base.Authorize() in the end

Comment: I knew that ;) But now I have a different issue and am not finding anything on SO about it. Now that I'm overriding `AuthorizeCore` and passing it `HttpContextBase` I can't `filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);` And I can't find `Result` in `HttpContextBase`

Comment: You can try that in an override/new of OnAuthorization

Comment: That is what I was doing. See in my code above where it says `// Logic to add or remove roles.` It is based on the `projectId` in the `RouteData` and if the `projectId` is not found in the database I do the `filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);`. So if I do the `OnAuthorization` solution, we are back to authorization taking place before my roles are set. :/